# Apt times out with no error

Tags: networking, apt

I'm attempting to use Ubuntu on a corporate network, behind a proxy. Everything is working except for `apt`. I can use `wget`, `git clone`, browse the web in firefox, etc. THe only thing that's not working services related to apt, such as Software Updater and the Software Store.

I set the http proxy info in `/etc/apt/apt.conf`, and I know for certain that the proxy is authenticating properly when I do `sudo apt-get update` because if I use a wrong username and password I get authentication errors.

When I run apt-get update, I get output like this.

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntulinux.jp/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntulinux.jp/ubuntu-ja-non-free xenial InRelease    
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntulinux.jp/ubuntu-ja-non-free xenial Release
Hit:5 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]
Ign:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                       
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]
0% [7 InRelease 102 kB/102 kB 100%]
```

It seems to connect, but the download never starts. I have the timeout set to 15 seconds, so after fifteen seconds it gives up and goes to the next resource, but never succeeds in getting any of them. No error is thrown that specifically says anything about timing out. I have tried many mirrors. The automatic mirror finder itself fails probably for the same reason.

I suspect the problem may be external to my machine, but I need a way to identify the problem so I can know one way or the other for certain. Ideally, I'd be able to fix this on my end, without having to get IT involved.

UPDATE:
apt-cache search works. 
If I leave apt-get update running for several hours, some files do get downloaded, but not enough to actually do anything.

UPDATE 2:
I found out that the proxy server is getting a 404 error, but that it doesn't seem to be making it back to my machine, which results in the timeout. Any advice on that front?

Comment: I'm just guessing here because I just answered a similar question about updating behind a proxy, try recreating the apt list as documented here, https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=819775#p819720

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I gave that a shot, but the symptoms are still the same.